# Yocto Build git directory is missing for Kernel

Tags: kernel, yocto, porting

I downloaded yocto, activated beaglebone as machine. Then I build core-image-minimal. I wanted to do kernel and u-boot modification.

But "git" directory of the following path is missing: 
`<build dir>/tmp/work/<machine>/<kernel-name>/<kernel-version>/git/`

I have git directory for u-boot but not for kernel. Does anyone know, what can be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel source directory is located in ${TMPDIR}/work-shared/${MACHINE}/kernel-source.

By default $TMPDIR is tmp inside your build directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer aehs29, I was reading document which explains how to modify kernel and device tree. Document was telling, kernel is on the following path;

/tmp/work/imx6q_openrex-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-openrex/3.14-r0/git

Do you know, why u boot is on /work/ directory, but kernel is on /work-shared/ ?

Comment: Directory of kernel source depends on the layer of manufacturer or is it standard?